# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat behavoiur

Tags: php, date, datetime

Today I've encountered something confusing for me with the behaviour of the `\DateTime::createFromFormat` function.

In my case I have a string, representing the date in the following format `m/Y (05/2017)`. When I want to convert the string to DateTime object I've encountered the following issue:

`$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '02/2017');`

When I dump the `$date` variable, the date property inside is `'2017-03-03 11:06:36.000000'`

But if I add the date before the month `$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/02/2017');` I get back an object with correct date property. (unfortunately I cant change the format of the date and add the day. It must be m/Y).

The fix I've come up with is to concatenate the first day of the month to the date string I have `$date = '01/'.$dateString;` but I rather not to do that because it's hardcoded.

What is wrong here? Does the createFromFormat function lack information of how to create the object? I'm quite confused with this. Thanks for everyone's help in advance!

Comment: this just creates the object, var_dump $date->format() (format is the same as date, so Y-m-d still applies etc.) and you should see what you're expecting :)

Comment: It populates missing data with today's data (day 31) and adjusts to skip invalid dates. Helpful or not, is like most date functions work in PHP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, PHP will populate missing date values with those of the current date/time; so

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '02/2017');
```

will populate the missing day value with the current date; and as 31st February is an invalid date, it will roll forward into March. Likewise, hours/minutes/seconds will be populated with the missing time values based on the current time.

If you want to force the behaviour of forcing to the beginning of the month/time, then modify your mask with a leading `!`

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!m/Y', '02/2017');
```

This will populate the missing day with the 1st of the month, and the time with `00:00:00`

Alternatively, a trailing `|` will have the same effect

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y|', '02/2017');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This is something I'll know for the next time :)

Comment: The `!` and `|` syntaxes are awesome and appear to have existed for [quite long](https://3v4l.org/YvIkt).

Comment: It's interesting to read the [exact specs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) to understand how the `!` and `|` codes work. Basically they set values to Unix Epoch—we get day 1 because it happened to be 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store incomplete dates, not at least in a dedicated date format that can be used for complex date calculations (nothing prevents you from creating your own `MonthYear` class). So when you create a `DateTime()` object with incomplete information something needs to happen:

- Crash
- Use some default values

PHP opts for the second option and makes a decision inherited from the C language date library:

1. Assume that missing data means "now"
2. Try to fix automatically the invalid dates that this algorithm can create

In this case, `Feb 2017` becomes `31 Feb 2017` (because "now" is `31 May 2017`) and PHP follows this reasoning: February only had 28 days in year 2017 but I have three more; the user probably wants to move these three extra days into March. Thus `3 Mar 2017`.

I see no reason to avoid hard-coding `01` because, after all, it **is** a hard-coded value (why the first day of the month and not the last one or any other day?).

```
$input = '05/2017';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "01/$input");
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the functionality! The thing is that I always try to avoid hardcoding values, but this time It seems PHP does the same thing. I guess hardcoding '01' is the same as adding '!m/Y' as explained in the above answer.

Comment: Essentially it is. But I didn't even know you could use `!` until today.

Comment: I mean that Mark Baker's answer suggested using the `!` and it turns out that it does the same thing :)  Thank you very much, again.